# How can I stop multiple spaces from clearing form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm working on a simple form and javascript validation function. The only problem I have is that more than one space will read as a valid entry. I need to be sure that the form is actually filled out rather than someone just putting two spaces in each field and submitting the form. How can I stop this from happening? Is there some way to return false if the first character is a space, or to read any number of spaces with no other characters as false?

Comment: Use `.trim` on the value

Answer (score 0):

Use the string trim function to trim the string before validating. It should trim leading and trailing spaces. I've included an example below and you can see more documentation on [trim documentation from Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

```js
var demoInput = document.getElementById('multipleSpaces');
var demoText = demoInput.value;

var output = document.getElementById('output');

alert('Initial text length: ' + demoText.length + ' \n trimmed length ' + demoText.trim().length);
```

```html
<input type='text' value='  ' id='multipleSpaces'/>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello as Joel mentioned if you want to delete **trailing** spaces you can use **.trim()**. and if you want to normalize the string to have just 1 space you can use the following snippet.

```
var str = "this     is sparta   ";
    str = str.trim()
    str = str.split(/[ ]{2,}/).join(' ')

//output: "this is sparta"
```

Regex `/[ ]{2,}/` looks for more than 1 spaces and splits the string, then `.join(' ')` compiles splitted elements into 1 string. you can shorten it down to following:

> `str = str.trim().split(/[ ]{2,}/).join(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using built-in [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) and not rolling your own, this seems like a great use case for for the `<input>` element's [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) attribute.  Combined with a required attribute, this should accomplish what you want without any JS:

```
<form>
    <input
        type="text"
        pattern=".*\S.*"
        title="Must contain non-whitespace characters"
        required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=pattern) to ensure that the attribute is functional in your target environments.